# error with graphviz in python after i put it in the environment varaible

Tags: python, keras

i am in python i am try to visualize my neural network using graphviz lib
first i insall pydot using pip install pydot
then i insall graphviz using the following link

> https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html

download  the .msi file  then i go to environment variables and
    put the path  C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe  after
    that i still get the following error

when i run this code   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot.exe`

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
plot_model(model, to_file='model_plot.png', show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=True)




OSError: `pydot` failed to call GraphViz.Please install GraphViz (https://www.graphviz.org/) and ensure that its executables are in the $PATH.
```

i asked what the error in my steps 
who can i solve this problem
thanks in advance

i reached to the solution 
two lines should be added

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'
```

Comment: "Download the .msi file" is not the final step of installing GraphViz.  Did you actually run that file to install it?

Comment: yes , i reached to the solution

Comment: in code we should add this two lines                                                                               import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'

Comment: i added it to the question thank you

Comment: _i reached to the solution two lines should be added_ Doing that within your program is probably a bad idea.

Comment: why consider bad ??